# problem with cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins

in a cordova project I incorporated the cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin but adding this gives me this problem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 6s
45 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 40 up-to-date
```

removing this plugin everything works fine.
So this plugin is decrepit?
and how could I replace it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you more specific error output?
I believe ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' is a generic error and you should get some more information somewhere in your terminal.
This plugin has several issues, we use the fork, to circumvent some of them: cordova-plugin-file-transfer-ios-fix

Also, the plugin doesn't work with cordova 11.
Lastly, the plugin is reportedly deprecated and you might wanna consider getting it's replacement (XMLHttpRequest) to work instead of spending effort on this plugin.